# Extra character added using {#emit SetupSetting("AppId")} in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup

I'm having problems using the following code, it's adding an extra "{".

For example:

```
[Setup]
AppID={{E643099E-1ECE-474F-B043-1E7A7CE405AA}

[Code]
const
  INSTALL_KEY = 'Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{#emit SetupSetting("AppId")}_is1';
```

Returns the following:

```
INSTALL_KEY = 'Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{{E643099E-1ECE-474F-B043-1E7A7CE405AA}_is1';
```

Which obviously won't work detecting that key with RegKeyExists(HKLM, INSTALL_KEY) because of the extra "{" that isn't in the real path and the script won't compile if you remove the extra character in [Setup] because then it thinks it's a constant.

Answer (score 2):

The issue looks to be resolved on later versions of Inno Setup (5.5.5). Following code works just fine:

```
[Setup]

AppId={{********-****-****-****-********}
...

[code]

sAppId := ExpandConstant('{#emit SetupSetting("AppId")}_is1');
sUnInstPath := ExpandConstant('Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\') + sAppId;
```

Comment: It was not resolved by later versions. It's resolved by your call to `ExpandConstant`. What is the correct way, not hacking it using `StringChange` as in the answer by @Ignitor.

Answer (score 1):

I think that parser doesn't allow to use the custom constants enclosed by the `{}` characters, because they are used as introductors for [`the constants`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=consts), so I think you will have to workaround it. Here is one of the options:

```
[Setup]
AppID=E643099E-1ECE-474F-B043-1E7A7CE405AA

[code]
const
  INSTALL_KEY = '...\Uninstall\{{#emit SetupSetting("AppId")}}_is1';
```

My guess is that case you've described is just an unexpected bug, because the compiler prompts you to use double bracket in the beginning of your constant though but when you emit such constant you get it with the same double bracket back.

Comment: Wouldn't that change the registry key to "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\E643099E-1ECE-474F-B043-1E7A7CE405AA_is1" making the brackets useless for the test?

Comment: Actually yes, but I'm afraid there's no way to declare it as a constant with the brackets, so in this case I would just leave them (I know, it's not as standard as it might be).

Comment: Did you resolved this ? I'm just asking to close the old questions of you, somehow... :-)

Answer (score 1):

Use `StringChange()` to remove the extra `{`:

```
[Setup]
AppID={{E643099E-1ECE-474F-B043-1E7A7CE405AA}

[Code]
const INSTALL_KEY = '...\Uninstall\{#emit StringChange(SetupSetting("AppId"),"{{","{")}_is1';
```

Comment: While this works, one should better use `ExpandConstant` function as shown in the answer by @user3324751.

Comment: Username of the account with the correct answer has changed to @Cobra91151

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to use [`ExpandConstant`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_expandconstant) function as already mentioned by others.

```
[Setup]
AppId={{E643099E-1ECE-474F-B043-1E7A7CE405AA}
```

```pascal
[Code]
var
  INSTALL_KEY: String;

function InitializeSetup(): Boolean;
begin
  INSTALL_KEY := ExpandConstant('Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{#SetupSetting("AppId")}_is1');
  MsgBox(INSTALL_KEY, mbInformation, MB_OK);
end;
```

This is the expected behavior, not a bug. In `[Code]` section, [constants](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=consts) and [scripted constants](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptconstants) are not expanded while [emit preprocessor directives](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/index.php?topic=emit) `{#emit ...}`/`{#...}` are replaced with their values by ISPP. So you need to use ExpandConstant function to convert `{{` to `{`.

In this case, you can't define `INSTALL_KEY` as a Pascal constant as `ExpandConstant` function is used.

Answer (score 0):

You could also define your application ID as a constant and use it like this:

```
#define MyAppID "{{E643099E-1ECE-474F-B043-1E7A7CE405AA}"

[Setup]
AppId={#MyAppID}

[Code]
const INSTALL_KEY = '...\Uninstall\' + ExpandConstant('{#MyAppID}') + '_is1';
```